# Convert every JPG file to single mp4 video with specific duration

Tags: ffmpeg, type-conversion, jpeg, mp4

I have a folder with 100 jpg files, I want to convert each photo to a single MP4 video with a duration of 3 seconds in a bulk, I'm using Windows 10.

So, I will end up with 100 MP4 files each one of them is 3 Seconds.

Comment: The answer will likely depend on your Operating System.

Comment: @MarkSetchell it is Windows

Comment: Well, you can do one video with `ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.jpg -t 3 out.mp4` and you can loop over files with `FOR` https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html